# Google App Script unhiding rows when it shouldn't be?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm in the process of creating a checklist in Google Sheets and using App Script to show and hide various rows of the spreadsheet based on cell values.

I have code that works fine in one section of the sheet, but when I use the exact same piece of code (with variables renamed, etc.) the code doesn't want to work correctly.  For some reason it seems to be unhiding the rows that it's meant to be hiding.

The code appears to run correctly for an instant, but it then unhides the extra rows that are meant to remain hidden.  This only appears to be happening when changing the dropdown values in column H.

The code in question that doesn't want to work correctly is as follows:

```
function techTwoChecks() {
  // GLOBAL VARIALBES
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CF-510");

  // TECHNICAL FINDING VARIABLES
  var tech2PR1 = sheet.getRange('L45').getValue();
  var tech2PR2 = sheet.getRange('L51').getValue();
  var tech2PR3 = sheet.getRange('L57').getValue();


  // TECHNICAL FINDING ONE
  // PR Check 1
  if(sheet && tech2PR1 == 1) {
    sheet.showRows(50,6)
  }
  if(sheet && tech2PR1 == 0) {
    sheet.hideRows(50,14)
  }
  // PR Check 2
  if(sheet && tech2PR2 == 1) {
    sheet.showRows(56,6)
  }
  if(sheet && tech2PR2 == 0) {
    sheet.hideRows(56,8)
  }
  // PR Check 3
  if(sheet && tech2PR3 == 1) {
    sheet.showRows(62,6)
  }
  if(sheet && tech2PR3 == 0) {
    sheet.hideRows(62,3)
  }
}
```

Here's a link to the spreadsheet in question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OIKJG3l3_E6NF1FnhirvcgS4x7LJLEl6N7d_heRwXeM/edit?usp=sharing

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @Cooper I've just updated the question to now include the code that's causing the issue.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the code

Comment: About `This only appears to be happening when changing the dropbox values in column H.`, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the cell values of "L45", "L51", and "L57" are updated by the value of column "H" with a formula. Isn't this your expected situation? Or, this is the reason for your current issue? And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: I've tried replicating the issue and the code seems working as expected. Tried changing the "H45" to Yes (in L45 that is equals to 0) and it hides the rows starting from 50 to 64. I suggest that you provide the sample input and expected output so we can better help.